# Как избавиться черной области при изменении размеров окна wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

Я программно регулирую изменение размеров окна. И при уменьшении размеров появляется черная область, которая исчезает при нажатии на окно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается, что окно фризиться при изменении размеров и за счет этого появляется черная область.

Вот код в котором изменяются размеры:

```
     this.MinWidth = 510;
     this.MaxWidth = 510;
     this.MaxHeight = 315;
     this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.NoResize;
     this.contentControl.Content = this.logInControl;
```

Я пробовала добавлять метод `UpdateLayout()` и `InvalidateVisual()`, но они не помогли. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как избавиться от этой черной области при смене размеров окна.

[**Edit**] Код разметки

```
  <Window x:Class="LoginWindowForAras.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LoginWindowForAras"
        xmlns:gif="http://wpfanimatedgif.codeplex.com"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="Log In" Height="315" Width="510" FontFamily="Time New Roman" FontSize="16"
        MinWidth="510"  MinHeight="315" Background="#FFD7D7D7" Icon="images/aras.png" KeyDown="MainWindow_KeyDown" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid x:Name="mainGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" >
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" Margin="0,0,0,0"  Grid.Column="0"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Background="#FF646464" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.Column="1">
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Содержание окна регултруется с помощью юзер контролов. Добавляю еще код изменения размеров для контрола с которого пользователь может перейти на контрол логина.

```
this.ResizeMode = ResizeMode.CanResize;
this.MinWidth = 575;
this.MaxWidth = Double.PositiveInfinity;
this.MaxHeight = Double.PositiveInfinity;
this.contentControl.Content = checkInControl;
```

Ситуация с черной областью возникает тогда, когда сделать ресайз - окно на весь экран, а затем перейти на контрол логина, нажав соответствующую кнопку на сайд баре.

[**Edit**] Скрины отображения ситуации:

Сначала пользователь логинится, окно имеет фиксированные размеры.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После успешной авторизации в окне меняется юзер контрол на Check in. Сначала оно имеет размеры, которые задаются в коде при переходе на этот контрол.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но его размеры можна менять. И в случаии когда размеры окна сделать на весь экран и после этого нажать на кнопку Log out на сайт баре визникает ситуация з черной областью как на самом первом скрине в вопросе. Но если я растягиваю окно з контролом Check in'а просто стрелочками - проблем нету, окно при переходе на контрол логина появляется в центре и с такими размерами как нужно, без черных участков.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Покажите разметку окна

Comment: @АндрейNOP отредактировала вопрос

Comment: Давайте минимальный самодостаточный пример для воспроизведения проблемы, пока ничего "криминального" не вижу

Comment: @АндрейNOP отредактировала)

Comment: Я в вашем коде не вижу как вы меняете размеры окна. MinWidth/MaxWidth меняют только максимальные/минимальные размеры, но не текущие

Comment: @АндрейNOP, текущие размеры окна я не трогаю, чтобы могла ресайзаться datagrid

Comment: Я вас не понимаю, первое предложение вопроса: *Я программно регулирую изменение размеров окна.*

Comment: @АндрейNOP указывая Max/Min Width/Height

Comment: Но это не изменит же фактических размеров окна, почему не менять сразу `Width`?

Comment: @АндрейNOP потому что если задавать Width через код, тогда не будет срабатывать ресайз. Я нашла решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;`
- для Log in

`this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;`
 - для Check in

Но тогда есть проблема с тем, что окно появляется в левом углу, а не в центре экрана.